# How does Airflow parse and store schedule_interval

Tags: airflow

I am working on a feature that requires schedule_intervals of Airflow jobs. Instead of writing the code to parse cron expressions in the DAG files myself, I have been trying to find parsed schedule_interval values in Airflow metadata DB, but to no avail.

Can someone give me a pointer to how Airflow parses schedule_interval expressions (e.g. a file at https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow), and where it stores the parsed values (if the values are stored)?

#### Edit:

1. The schedule_interval expression above is the DAG argument schedule_interval, as in:

   > dag = DAG(
   >      'tutorial', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@daily')

According to [this documentation page](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html#dag-runs), schedule_interval can be a cron expression, a datetime.timedelta object, or one of the 'presets' like '@daily'. Because schedule_interval can take multiple forms, I don't want to re-invent the wheel and write code to parse schedule_interval arguments, if Airflow has already parsed and stored these values.

2. I am building a system to periodically check all Airflow jobs and summarize their status, through querying the Airflow metadata db. Although not absolutely necessary, it would be useful to know schedule_interval, because it reveals information such as for each Airflow job, how many dag runs are expected in the last 24 hours, and when the next dag run would be.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Do you mean this https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html#dag-runs by schedule_interval expressions? Also, what do you want to solve that you need to access the metadata db?

Comment: Same here, I can't understand you :( try to write pseudocode here in order to see your problem.

Comment: @tobi6 Yes, I was referring to the DAG argument schedule_interval. I have edited my question to address your comment. Hope it helps to clarify your questions. Thanks!

Comment: This might help https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-queries/

Comment: @tobi6 I couldn't find anything directly related to my question there, however I do think this page is a great resource of learning Airflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `schedule_interval` value isn't stored anywhere but the process itself. Airflow determines when it's time to create a new run by checking, more or less, `NOW() >= (MAX(execution_date, start_date)) + schedule_interval`

You can programmatically calculate Airflow's `execution_date` values with the `airflow.models.DAG.following_schedule` and `airflow.models.DAG.previous_schedule` methods if you'd like.

*Note*: Airflow uses the [`croniter`](https://github.com/taichino/croniter) package to calculate off cron values.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't manage to find where Airflow store parsed value of schedule_interval, however I did find the code that parses schedule_interval expressions. It's in the utils module (https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/utils/dates.py).